# HTML and CSS spacing issues

Tags: html, css

There is a gap between the breadcrumbs and the heading! I cant figure out how to remove it?

http://www.perfectclaims.com/ppiclaimsnew/index.php

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to just put a spam link in your question?

Comment: Sorry!

There is a gap between where it says "PPIClaimsUk.co.uk » Home" and the heading "Start Your PPI Claim NowAnd Get
Your Money Back on A NO WIN-NO FEE Basis..."

It it just white space! I would like to move the heading up so there is less white space!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p tag has a default top margin (of 1em?)

try resetting this or use a reset stylesheet

```
p { margin-top : 0 }
```